# Subscript out of bounds error when using an adjacency matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix, igraph

I get an error when applying a function to an adjacency matrix in R.

The adjacency matrix looks like this:

```
s2
    1   2   3   4   5   7   8   9   6
1   0   1   2   3   3   0   0   0   0
2   1   0   0   0   1   1   2   2   0
3   2   0   0   0   0   1   0   4   2
4   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   3   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   0   2   4   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

The code is as follows:

```
library(igraph)

library(egonet)

x<-index.egonet(s2)
```

when I apply `index.egonet` it gives me the error `subscript out of bounds`.

Any help or solution to the problem will highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your EGO subject (parameter `ego.name`) is not defined.

The following, defining the first person as the ego person works:

```
library(igraph)
library(egonet)
s2 <- c(0,1,2,3,3,0,0,0,0,
1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,0,
2,0,0,0,0,1,0,4,2,
3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,2,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0)
s2 <- matrix(s2,nrow=9)

colnames(s2) <- rownames(s2) <- paste0(as.character(c(1:5,7:9,6)))
x<-index.egonet(s2,ego.name = "1")
```